# How do I adjust my docker set up so that localstack file storage persists between system restarts?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, localstack, volumes

I have this docker-compose.yml file with a localstack image that i use to simulate S3 storage

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  localstack: 
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    environment: 
      - DEFAULT_REGION=ap-northeast-1
      - EDGE_PORT=4566
      - SERVICES=s3,logs
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-1
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxx
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
    ports: 
      - '4566-4583:4566-4583'
    volumes:
      - ./make_bucket.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d/make_bucket.sh
```

The "make_bucket.sh" script consists of

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3 mb s3://my-bucket
```

When I run "docker-compose up," everything runs fine, and I am able to upload files into my bucket, but when I stop my container (using Ctrl + C for instance) and then restart it later, or when my system blue screens (because it is Windows) and I restart, my volumes have been destroyed and my images are no longer present.  Is there a way I can configure my docker-compose file so that my files persist between restarts?

**Edit:** I'm not wed to using localstack -- if I had any imaeg that could mimic S3 storage and could persist data across restarts I'd be happy.

Comment: See [LocalStack volume](https://docs.localstack.cloud/references/filesystem/#localstack-volume) in the LocalStack documentation.

Comment: There is [MinIO](https://github.com/minio/minio), an OSS alternative to S3. It can persist data without any extra requirements (aside from docker volume).

Answer (score 0):

`DATA_DIR` has been deprecated with LocalStack [v1.0.0](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/releases/tag/v1.0.0). Simply setting `PERSISTENCE=1` as your environment variable should enable persistence.

However, keep in mind that persistence is a Pro-only feature.
If you are interested, Cloud Pods now offer all users the possibility to snapshot the instance state and restore it at will. Check out more [here](https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/tools/cloud-pods/community/).

Comment: So I understand what you're describing, I can only persist across restarts if I pay a fee to someone?

Comment: I replaced my "DATA_DIR" env var with "PERSISTENCE:=1", rebuilt, restarted, and retested and this didn't work.

Comment: Hei @Dave, you can persist your state by using Cloud Pods. That's a feature partially opened to all users. You can do `localstack pod save file://<abs_path_on_disk` to take a snapshot of your instance. To reload it in the future just do `localstack pod load file://<abs_path_on_disk`. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Persistence is [documented here](https://docs.localstack.cloud/references/persistence-mechanism/), it specifies:

> To enable the persistence mechanism simply set the PERSISTENCE environment variable to 1
>
> Note that persistence is a Pro feature, therefore the LOCALSTACK_API_KEY must also be set.

it means that:

- **You need a [Pro subscription](https://localstack.cloud/pricing/)** to enable persistence (with which you'll get an API Key). Without it, setting `PERSISTENCE=1` will NOT enable persistence.
- Once you have your Pro subscription (and API Key), you can use a Docker Compose config such as:

```yaml
    environment:
      # Persistence needs Pro sub with API Key
      - LOCALSTACK_API_KEY=YourApiKey
      - PERSISTENCE=1
    volumes:
      - localstack-data:/var/lib/localstack"

volumes:
  localstack-data: {}
```

Comment: It is not an option to pay any money to achieve my solution.  As I mentioned in my edit, happy to use something other than localstack if it gets me where I want to go.